# telebot python ошибка TypeError

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет, в моем боте есть заполнение данных, работает через register_next_step_handler, когда я вместо текста отправляю боту либо фото, либо другой документ, то программа завершается с ошибкой TypeError, как ее можно обработать грамотно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему через `if message.content_types='text':`